# OutOfMemoryException when large number of Unit Tests in a Resharper Unit Test session

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, nunit, resharper-2017

I am working on a large C# project with 1000+ unit tests. When I run all the test of the project in a session, after 10-12 mins many tests start throwing OutOfMemoryException. When I run them separately they run fine. When I run the whole session on my colleague's machine - they all run fine (and ends in 30-40 mins). Specs:

Nunit 2.6, Resharper 2017.1,  VS 2013, Win8, 16GB RAM, 8 logical processors

Comment: First you need to check ReSharper settings to see if you explicitly run the unit test cases in a 64 bit process. As such settings can be set at multiple levels (machine wide, user wide, and project wide), not surprised that some machine works while others not.

Comment: NUnit 2.6 is not the latest NUnit V2 release. It has been a long time, but I believe that a number of memory issues were dealt with in the four following releases up to 2.6.4.